# Issues right after importing into unity

Tags: airconsole

Immediately upon importing I am given multiple errors for unity. Everything imports cleanly but I have 32 errors all very similar saying.

> Assets/AirConsole/plugins/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs(31,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace `System.Xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/AirConsole/plugins/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs(603,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XObject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/AirConsole/plugins/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs(34,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace `System.Xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Those just being a few and I was wondering if I am missing anything or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some sort of import error. Last time I've encountered it, deleting my Library folder (thus forcing a reimport) resolved the issue.

Edit: Another source of the issue could be that your project is not set to HTML5/WebGL.